# Dynamic Top 10 Lists Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

looking for some help on creating some widget type top 10 lists for making it easier for my staff to see specific sales figures. Below is a breakdown of the data we have.

```
Product Type   Product code   Sales
A              AAA1           100
A              AAA2           200
A              AAA3           150
B              BBB1           100
```

In total there is roughly 1000 products with 6 product types.
I would like to be able to display 6 short tables with the top 10's of each product type on a new tab.

Comment: Why an entirely new table? I would think just add a new column called like *Top Product* or something and have a formula which displays "Yes" (or whatever text you want) if it is the top product in that category (and blank otherwise). Then you can just use a filter to display only those rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a PivotTable easily enough. Plenty of examples on Google...just google "PivotTable" and "Top Ten". Don't be afraid of the name...PivotTables are the easiest thing in the world when you've whipped up a few.